# Android: create intents in notification to launch calendar or web

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar

I want to create notification with the ability to create the notified event in the calendar or to launch a web pages for more infos.

So my code is:

```
private void sendNotification(String title, String msg, String website, String startDate, String endDate) {
    long eventStartInMillis = 0, eventEndInMillis = 0;
    Notification.Builder mBuilder = null;

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

    Uri ringURI = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    try {
        if (website != null) webIntent.setData(Uri.parse(website));
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.d(Constants.APP_TAG, "NullPointerException " + e);
    }

    PendingIntent webPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, webIntent, 0);

    try {
        Date startEventDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy hh:mm", Locale.getDefault()).parse(startDate);
        Date endEventDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy hh:mm", Locale.getDefault()).parse(endDate);
        eventStartInMillis = startEventDate.getTime();
        eventEndInMillis = endEventDate.getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.d(Constants.APP_TAG, "ParseException " + e);
    }

    Intent calIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);

    calIntent.setData(Events.CONTENT_URI);
    calIntent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, title);
    calIntent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, msg);
    calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, eventStartInMillis); 
    calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, eventEndInMillis);

    PendingIntent calPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, calIntent, 0);

    mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_guide_48)
    .setContentTitle(title)
    .setSound(ringURI)
    .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
    .setContentText(msg)
    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
    .addAction(R.drawable.calendar_48, "Note it!", calPendingIntent)
    .addAction(R.drawable.web_48, "More infos", webPendingIntent)
    ;

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

}
```

So the calendar, or the web browser are launched but without any data; The created event has no title, no description, no date..., and the web starts without url.

What's my mistake here?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You need to set properties of the intents like so:

```
Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
            i.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.nscc.ca"));
            startActivity(i);
```

Check the validity of your `website` variable's state.

Comment: Well thanks for your help Ray, you are right, replacing Intent.VIEW by "android.intent.action.VIEW" makes the web intent to work !?! But it seems that's not the solution for calendar Intent. I used "android.intent.action.INSERT", but the event remains empty. I'm sure it's close to what you suggested maybe because I'm sure I got it working but in all my tests, I certainly changed a detail somewhere.

Comment: Glad to be of help! The syntax for the calender differs from the web intent. Try this: `Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
        i.setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
` 
There's more information 
[here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intents) Cheers.

Comment: Any luck? Be sure mark this question as answered to give back to the people who helped you. (In this case, me.)

Comment: Unfortunately not Ray, As you can see in my code, I use Intent.ACTION_INSERT and unfortunately, the created event is still empty. I wrote my code based on the doc you you pointed me out and I also copied/pasted the exact same code snippet without success. Maybe the addAction() function has some particularity with this intent. So the web intent works well, I also tried geo intent, no problem, but the calendar intent doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

So, I discovered that ACTION_INSERT is not the correct way to add a prefilled event, we must use ACTION_EDIT.

So for those interested on how to generated a notification event with the ability to find it on a map, by choosing you prefered map application, add it in calendar or go the a 'more infos' web page, everything is below:

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
private void sendNotification(String title, String msg, String location, String latitude, String longitude, String website, String startDate, String endDate) {
    Date startEventDate = null;
    Date endEventDate = null;

    NotificationManagerCompat mNotificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

    Uri ringURI = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


    Intent webIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");

    try {
        if (website != null) webIntent.setData(Uri.parse(website));
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.d(Constants.APP_TAG, "NullPointerException " + e);
    }

    PendingIntent webPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, webIntent, 0);

    //String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%s,%s,ICI", latitude, longitude);
    String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", 44.221149, 3.357192);
    Intent geoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));

    PendingIntent geoPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, geoIntent, 0);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {

        try {
            startEventDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm", Locale.getDefault()).parse(startDate);
            endEventDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm", Locale.getDefault()).parse(endDate);

            Intent calIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT)
            .setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
            .putExtra(Events.TITLE, title)
            .putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, msg)
            .putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startEventDate.getTime()) 
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endEventDate.getTime())
            .putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY)
            ;


            PendingIntent calPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, calIntent, 0);
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_guide_48)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setSound(ringURI)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg).setSummaryText(Constants.APP_TAG + "vous informe"))
            .setContentText(msg)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_place, null, geoPendingIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_new_event, null, calPendingIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_web_site, null, webPendingIntent)
            ;

            mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.d(Constants.APP_TAG, "ParseException " + e);
        }

    } else {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_guide_48)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setSound(ringURI)
        .setContentText(msg)
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_web_site, null, webPendingIntent)
        ;

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

    }

}
```

Good code!

Regards,
Alain